# Storing query result for later used in session or temp table or query one by one?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, session

Hi I am building a online quiz system and i am trying to figure out the best way to optimize the performance. Lets say there are total of 100 of quiz in the question bank and randomly pull 50 of them into a set of quiz. I am using Codeigniter framework.

What I am planning to do now was query the 50 question from database and store the query question with answer into temp_data(). User answer will be store in the temp-data as well. When user finished the quiz, all the answer and question will be inserted in one shot to the database. Session is destroyed.

So, is there any other more efficient way or this is it? Since cookies allowed 4kb so it is impossible to store it. i am thinking to use another table to store the answer but it involve query for each page and question load. But session kind of eat up memory as well. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CI cache library you can use different cache methods file,redis or memcache with this library, as you said you are selecting random 50 question for each user than create unique cache file save all questions and answers in that file, just save filename in session or cookie. on each question answered you can save directly to database or save in same cache file later save all answered question at once. have look on cache library

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html